# Mongo Compare Range of Numbers Represented as Strings

Tags: mongodb

How can I compare extremely large numbers represented as strings with mongo?

From and to values could be a string representing a very large number

```
collection.find({ fromValue: { $gte: '1' }, toValue: { $lte: '100' } })
```

Comment: Why are you using string here to compare numbers?

Comment: Also, what is the datatype of `fromValue` & `toValue` fields in the schema?

Comment: The number can be an extremely large number that would need to be represented as a string - larger than 64 bits up to 255 bits.

Comment: You can use [Collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) and specify the option `numericOrdering` to compare numbers in strings.

Comment: Yes Collation seems to be working. Thank you @prasad_

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has Decimal128 type which is a 128 bit floating point number.

For even larger numbers one strategy that might work is to stringify and left pad them (zeroes or spaces should work), then perform string comparisons which $lte etc. appear to support.